# How do I connect to some local DB server in MS SQL Server 2012?

Tags: database, sql-server, sql, database-administration

I installed MS SQL Server and now want to create some tables and do some queries ...
I need to have some local DB Server running to do that right?
When I installed SQL Server there was no option to select a local server to connect to...
What Authentication should I choose?
a)Windows
b)SQL Server - if this one, what credentials should I use?

Here is a picture how it looks when I open SQL Server Management Studio
[postimg.org/image/nffyjjx3p/](http://postimg.org/image/nffyjjx3p/)

I tried to connect to ACER-PC server (the name of my laptop) but it says:
Cannot connect to ACER-PC.

...or is it possible to create a database and do some queries on it without some DB Server running? I doubt it is possible...

Answer (score 2):

You installed SQL Server.  This is the local DB server that you need running.

With regard to the authentication, if you are connecting to a server on your local machine then you use Windows authentication which takes your windows user/pass to login to the db.  If you are connecting to a server that is not in your network/on your local machine then you use server authentication.  For this to work, the (database) server needs to have been setup with a logon and password which you type in.

To access a local server, you should be able to click the 'Server name:' drop-down and pick <Browse for more ...> which should show a (possibly single entry) list of database engines you can connect to.

If this doesn't show any entries, you may need to check the Sql Server post install instructions to get a database engine up and running.

Comment: Where are the *Sql Server post install* instructions located?

Comment: Instructions appear as part of the install wizard.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to logon to a SQL Server instance, you have to know what you did during the installation.

1. The SQL Server instance name is specified here. Did you select the default, or you specified a name for it?

[image]

2.What about the authentication type and SQL Server as account login?

[image]

3.When you start SQL Server Management Studio, in the Server name list click *Browse for more* and in the browse for servers dialog expand Database Engine

[image]

[image]

All local SQL Server instances will be listed. All you have to do is enter the correct password.